# Elixir Timezone Comparison for UTC and DateTime Struct

Tags: datetime, timezone, erlang, elixir, comparison

I am trying to compare two datetimes to see if they overlap. However, one is a DateTime struct and the other is a ~U[] time - this is how they come out of the database. I cannot work out how to do this - it would be good if I could compare them both in UTC and also keep the timezone awareness.

The two times I have are:
 `start_datetime_1 = ~U[2022-03-31 11:15:00.000000Z]`

and
`starttime_2 = #DateTime<2022-03-31 11:15:00.000000+01:00 BST Europe/London>`

I wanted to do something like:
`DateTime.compare(start_datetime_1, start_datetime_2 == :gt || :eq)`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

`~U[2022-03-31 11:15:00.000000Z]` is the same `DateTime` but in `UTC`. A sigil `~U[]` is just syntactic sugar.

You can do a comparison with [`DateTime.compare/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#compare/2) out of the box. It understands timezones.

```elixir
DateTime.compare(start_datetime_1, start_datetime_2) in [:gt, :eq]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, however, when I try and run the function in iex I get this error:
```* (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in DateTime.compare/2    

    The following arguments were given to DateTime.compare/2:

  
        # 1 "2022-03-25 01:00:00.058104+00"

        # 2 ~U[2022-03-25 12:00:00.058104Z]

    Attempted function clauses (showing 1 out of 1):
def compare(%{utc_offset: utc_offset1, std_offset: std_offset1} = datetime1, %{utc_offset: utc_offset2, std_offset: std_offset2} = datetime2)```
Do you know why this could be?

Comment: The first argument you are passing is a binary. It must be a `DateTime` instance. Call a `DateTime.from_iso8601/1` on it.